# Necesito ayuda en mi código javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy empezando en javascript y html y estoy haciendo un Tic tac toe.
Tengo el problema de que cuando trato de que muestre el X o el O en el botón y se desactive no me muestra nada acá el código, comenten errores:

```html
    <html>
<head>
 <style>
 input[type = "button"]{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  color:#349913;
  border-color:#12200D; 

 }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton1" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton2" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton3" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);"><br>
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton4" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton5" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton6" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);"><br>
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton7" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton8" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
    <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton9" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
<script>

 function tateti(clicked){
       var bandera=true;
        boton1=document.getElementById(clicked);
   
       }
  if(bandera==true){
   boton1.value="x";
   boton1.disabled=true;
   bandera="1";
            
            }
       else{
         boton1.value="o";
         boton1.disabled=true;
         bandera=true
         

         }
        
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, mira bien tu funcipon, tienes un `}` de más, ¿es eso a lo que te refieres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenías varios errores.
Me tomé la libertad de corregirlos y mejorar un poco el código

1. Tenías un `}` de más.
2. La variable `bandera` debe estar fuera del cuerpo de la función, de lo contrario siempre estarás reiniciandola en `true` y por lo tanto siempre será el turno de ´X´
3. Al finalizar la ejecución del if deberías asignar bandera a `false` no a `1`
4. Para que no se muevan los botones al hacer clic puedes colocar un espacio en blanco `" "` como value de los botones
5. (Opcional) No necesitas los `id` en los botones si le pasas `this` es decir el mismo botón directamente a la función
6. (Opcional) En el `if` no es necesario compararlo contra `true` ya que al evaluar la variable ya retorna el valor `boolean` esperado
7. (Opcional) Ya que el botón siempre se desactiva y la bandera siempre se cambia, puedes mover esas dos instrucciones fuera del `if`
8. (Opcional) Ahora que el `if` es realmente simple, puedes simplificarlo mas usando el operador `?:`
9. (Opcional) En lugar de tener una variable global `bandera` lo cual puede que no sea una buena práctica, puedes almacenarla como propiedad de la misma función `tateti`

```js
function tateti(boton) {
    boton.value = tateti.bandera ? "x" : "o"; 
    boton.disabled = true;
    tateti.bandera = !tateti.bandera;
}

tateti.bandera = true;
```

```css
input[type="button"] {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #349913;
    border-color: #12200D;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)"><br>
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)"><br>
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
```

10. (Opcional) Con respecto al punto 9. Aún tiene un problema. La variable `bandera` (o `tateti.bandera`) aún es posible modificarlo desde afuera de la función. Se puede solucionar si se captura la variable mediante un IIFE ([Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)) encapsulándola de forma que no sea accesible desde afuera de la función

```js
var tateti = (function() {
    var bandera = true;
    
    return function(boton) {
        boton.value = bandera ? "x" : "o"; 
        boton.disabled = true;
        bandera = !bandera;
    }
})();
```

```css
input[type="button"] {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #349913;
    border-color: #12200D;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)"><br>
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)"><br>
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
<input type="button" name="boton1" value=" " onclick="tateti(this)">
```

Answer (score 1):

Varias correcciones se tuvo que hacer a tu código:

- Primero la llave `}` extra que tenías
- Corregir el asignar el valor a tu variable `bandera`, si le asignas `"1"` este siempre será `true` puedes probarlo haciendo un `console.log("1" == true)`, se le debe asignar un valor de tipo `false` para que entre a tu `else`
- Dejar afuera de tu función la variable `bandera` de lo contrario siempre se inicializará en true y no se le asignará otro valor cuando mandes llamar a tu función.

```js
var bandera=true;

function tateti(clicked){
 console.log(bandera)
  boton1=document.getElementById(clicked);
  if(bandera==true){
    boton1.value="x";
    boton1.disabled=true;
    bandera=false;

  }
  else{
    boton1.value="o";
    boton1.disabled=true;
    bandera=true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton1" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton2" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton3" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);"><br>
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton4" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton5" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton6" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);"><br>
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton7" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton8" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
    <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton9" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
```

Answer (score -1):

Hola amigo solo tienes "}" despues del else como comento @César aqui tienes el codigo corregido :

```html
 <html>
<head>
 <style>
 input[type = "button"]{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  color:#349913;
  border-color:#12200D; 

 }
 </style>

</head>
<body>
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton1" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton2" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton3" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);"><br>
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton4" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton5" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton6" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);"><br>
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton7" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
 <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton8" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
    <input type="button"  name="boton1" id="boton9" value="" onclick="tateti(this.id);">
<script>

 function tateti(clicked){
       var bandera=true;
        boton1=document.getElementById(clicked);
   
       }
  if(bandera==true){
   boton1.value="x";
   boton1.disabled=true;
   bandera="1";
            
            }
       else{
         boton1.value="o";
         boton1.disabled=true;
         bandera=true
         

         }
        
  
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 porque el voto negativo ha sido injustificado.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz Este código no funciona, trata de ejecutarlo tu misma. Aparece el mensaje `Uncaught ReferenceError: bandera is not defined`

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz ahora sí, está justificado :) Aunque de igual modo, está bloqueado el voto.